# HTML form submit, .Net, save fields as XML

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

We have an HTML page with an form on it. 
We are prepopulating a form  from an XML file using jQuery AJAX.

We would like the form, on submit, to save over our default.xml file.  Most likely we will use ASP.Net as our server side.

Our question would be, what would the ASP.Net/C# look like in order to save the info in put in the form and save over our XML file.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

This is our example:

```
 <option id="timeBlockOne">
  <select>12:00</select>
  <select>1:00</select>
 </option>

<option id="titleBlockOne">
<select>Title One</select>
<select>Title Two</select>
</option>

 <option id="titleBlockTwo">
 <select>Title three</select>
 <select>Title Four</select>
 </option>

 <option id="timeBlockTwo">
 <select>12:00</select>
 <select>1:00</select>
 </option>

 ...etc up to 10 blocks.

  <button action="Post">Submit</button>
```

Desired XML output.

```
 <main>
    <itemOne>
      <timeBlockOneValue>Value selected from form</timeBlockOneValue>
      <titleBlockOneValue>Value Selected from form</titleBlockOneValue>
    </itemOne>
    <itemTwo>
      <timeBlockTwoValue>Value selected from form</timeBlockTwoValue>
      <titleBlockTwoValue>Value Selected from form</titleBlockTwoValue>
    </itemTwo>
     ...etc
 </main>
```

Hopefully this helps out with my question.

Comment: Too broad. There are couple questions/article around on [how to upload and save file with ASP.Net](http://www.bing.com/search?q=how+to+upload+and+save+file+with+ASP.Net) - you may want to check them out to make you question more concrete... Including [How to upload a file to a Web server in ASP.NET by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246) article on MSDN.

Comment: If your form is processed by server-side, then all elements should have runat="server", then you should be able to traverse all FORM components and get user input from each component then populate your xml file as you check each element. If not, you can traverse all FORM elements using JQuerey and once you are done you can invoke a C# WebMethod from JavaScript and pass a string with XML data, and then you can persist the XML file on the server-side. If you need help let me know.

Comment: @Lucidgold. I know about the runat="server" needs and that the page should be a Webform. I have done the invocation of C# webmethods from JS only a very few times. That is the issue. We would like to get the values of each of our <select><option> from our HTML form and then save the form submissions into an XML file.  Help would be greatly appreciated.  Code example would be much better.  C# and JS if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here is a possible way to get you on the right track, please let me know if this is not clear.

**JavaScript:**

```
function GetXMLButton() {
    var xml = "<main>";
    var i = 1;
    // Loop for each OPTION element in the myForm div
    $("#myform select").each(function() {
        // Get value of selected option.
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        xml = xml + "<item_" + i + "><" + this.id + ">" + selectedValue + "</" + this.id + "></item_" + i + ">";

        i++;
    });

    xml = xml + "</main>";

    // Call C# WebMethod to save into xml file
    PageMethods.SaveXMLFile(xml); 
}
```

**ASPX:** Make sure to set `EnablePageMethods = true` in the ScriptManager object. Also I think you might have switched your OPTION and SELECT tags, check your code, it should be SELECT then OPTION tag.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="fileupdatepanel">
        <ContentTemplate>

            <div id="myForm">
                <select id="timeBlockOne">
                    <option selected>12:00</option>
                    <option>1:00</option>
                </select>

                <select id="titleBlockOne">
                    <option>Title One</option>
                    <option selected>Title Two</option>
                </select>

                <select id="titleBlockTwo">
                    <option selected>Title three</option>
                    <option>Title Four</option>
                </select>

               <select id="timeBlockTwo">
                   <option>12:00</option>
                   <option selected>1:00</option>
               </select>
           </div>

       </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
 <asp:Button ID="button1" runat="server" Text="Get XML" OnClientClick="return GetXMLButton();" />
```

**C# Code-Behind:**
You need to reference the following:

```
using System.Web.Services;
```

Then add the following method and make sure you put `[WebMethod]` before method declaration:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SaveXMLFile(string formXMLData)   
{
    // Put your code to convert formXMLData string to an XML File and save/upload on/to server
}
```